# Render filename of file upload field in node template

Tags: 7

I have a field for uploading a file. And in *node--content_type.tpl.php* I want to just print the filename of the uploaded file.

So far I have this

```
$node = node_load($nid);
//get field item in correct language
$item = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_file_upload');
//get field_file_upload value
$output1 = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_file_upload', $item[0]);
print render($output1);
```

But it renders a link to the download and a thumbnail of the download type.

**I want to just print out the filename.** I tried using:

```
$output2 = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_file_upload', $item[0]['filename']);
print render($output2);
```

But this renders a thumbnail of the download type e.g PDF icon rather than showing the filename.

The printed array for $output1 is:

```
Array
(
    [#theme] => file_link
    [#file] => stdClass Object
        (
            [fid] => 196
            [display] => 1
            [description] => 
            [uid] => 1
            [filename] => drupal-7-theming-cheat-sheet.pdf
            [uri] => public://drupal-7-theming-cheat-sheet_0.pdf
            [filemime] => application/pdf
            [filesize] => 224804
            [status] => 1
            [timestamp] => 1348746651
            [type] => undefined
            [rdf_mapping] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [#access] => 1
)
```

The printed array for $output2 is:

```
Array
(
    [#theme] => file_link
    [#file] => stdClass Object
        (
            [scalar] => drupal-7-theming-cheat-sheet.pdf
        )

    [#access] => 1
)
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed a key in between. Try,

```
$output2 = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_file_upload', $item[0]);
foreach ($output2 as $key) {
  if(is_object($key)) {
    echo "File Name: ".$key -> filename;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @indrock it throws up an error when I try to print this
`Notice: Undefined index: #file in include()`

Comment: ahh, yes, thats because in array i can see that `#file` is an stdClass object and not a key. So, you should access it using `->` and not like general array keys. See the edit

Comment: `$output2 = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_file_upload', $item[0][]['filename']);` completely breaks drupal and stops it rendering anything else of the page :S

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, see the edit. It should work.

Comment: Great that works. If we are using `$item[0]` surely there is only ever one $output2? So can we tidy up `foreach ($output2 as $key) {
  if(is_object($key)) {
    echo "File Name: ".$key -> filename;
  }
}` somehow removing the `foreach`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but the `$output2` is an array with 3 elements, one of which `#file` is an object, which can't be accessed unless we know its name. And I'm not sure of the name of the object. above code won't cause any overhead, as it only checks for objects in `$output2` array.