# Before saving a node how to get the file path

Tags: 7

For a content type "TEST" which has a field "upload file", I want the file path before saving the node. 
hook_node_presave can be used to do anything before saving the node.
I want to rename the file before it get saved into database.

but my file is getting saved first into the database.

How to do rename a file before it gets saved into database in a custom module.

Comment: Useful information regarding uploading files goes here http://drupal.org/node/347251

Comment: useful link : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44957/render-filename-of-file-upload-field-in-node-template/44963#44963

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `hook_file_presave()` function.

You might have to additionally rename/move the file after it has been uploaded.

See also [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9744/how-do-i-change-the-uploaded-file-name-after-the-node-has-been-saved) thread and check the [File (Field) Paths](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) module as it might have already the functionality you need.