# How one can display the file path once it is successfully uploaded

Tags: 7, files

How one can display the file path in node/add page, once it is successfully uploaded, before saving the node.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below: **file_create_url($file->uri)**

```
function import_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Load the file.
  $file = file_load($form_state['values']['file_fid']);
  // Change status to permanent.
  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
  // Save.
  $uploaded = file_save($file);
  if ($uploaded == TRUE) {
    drupal_set_message(t('The file has been uploaded.'));
    dpm(file_create_url($file->uri));
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message(t('The file could not be uploaded. Please contact the site administrator.'), 'error');
  }

}
```

Also, refer the answer for [pre-node save function](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/47905/before-saving-a-node-how-to-get-the-file-path)

Comment: could you provide more information where to add this code ?

Comment: Please refer the hook_node_presave to do this. hook will be your module name.